# Restore or Reset a Scene using Transition Framework

Tags: android, android-animation

I was following a [tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-animations-android-transition-framework-part-1/) and want to do something of my own with it. The tutorial showed me how to animate. So I did that, now I want to restore the view(scene) that was before. First thing is to fade in the new views, which works fine, but restore/reset fails. It **should** behave like this:

[image]

I am setting `onClickListener` to menu strip (ImageView), and toggling `boolean` value to check if view is full or not. One issue I came across was that I had to reassign `onClickListener` when tansition ends, because new layout is inflating in transition. But when I click after three buttons are visible, it does not register my click (by debugging I checked).

here is code file:

```
public class HorizotalViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Transition.TransitionListener, View.OnClickListener
{


    boolean viewing = false;
    ImageView goButton;
    Scene scene, restoreScene;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_horizotal_view );

        ViewGroup sceneView = (ViewGroup) findViewById( R.id.sceneView );


        scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout( sceneView,
                R.layout.transition_example2, this );

        restoreScene = Scene.getSceneForLayout( sceneView,
                R.layout.transition_example, this );


        goButton = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.goButton );


        goButton.setOnClickListener( this );


    }



    @Override public void onTransitionStart( Transition transition )
    {

    }

    @Override public void onTransitionEnd( Transition transition )
    {
        goButton = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.goButton );


        goButton.setOnClickListener( this );
    }
//...

    @Override public void onClick( View view )
    {
        if ( !viewing )
        {
            TransitionManager.go( scene );
            viewing = true;
        }
        else
        {


            TransitionManager.go( restoreScene );

            //goToScene( restoreScene );


            viewing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are xml files:

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sceneView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.lgvalle.material_animations.HorizotalViewActivity">
<include layout="@layout/transition_example"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Default layout (transition_example.xml):

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scene"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/goButton"
           android:src="@drawable/menu"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Transition layout (transition_example2.xml):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scene"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/goButton"
        android:src="@drawable/menu"

        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/repeat"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/repeat"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/share"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I cannot see any issues with my logic, its self explaining,

1 - Check `boolean` if transition no.2 is already happened

1A - Do transition, update `boolean`.

2 - If transition happened

2A - Call previous scene, update `boolean`.

Now, I guess there is this problem with `onCickListener`, because I cant get to breakpoint in `onClickListener` once `TransitionManager.go()` is called, if it get register it might work as expected. There are no `logcat` errors/warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same with my project this is what i found out:

What happend when you use the Scene transition you have 2 View sets that will animate. lets say Set A (start layout) and Set B (End Layout). What you do in your code is that you set your clicklisteners on Set A. But after the Scene Transition set A is not on the screen anymore.

set your clicklisteners again after your transition will solve your problem.
(when you use a CustomView that contents values you need to "copy" aswell.

To achieve this, use [Scene.setEnterAction(Runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Scene.html#setEnterAction(java.lang.Runnable)) method,

```
scene.setEnterAction(new Runnable(){

@override
void run()
{

   goButton = (ImageView) scene.getSceneRoot.findViewById( R.id.goButton );


   goButton.setOnClickListener( this );

}

});
```

Comment: Hi I solved this and forgot to update, to achieve this, we use Scene.EnterAction(Runnable...) on both Scene objects. Edit your answer and I will accept it.